# Advanced WP columns shifts down in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am using Advanced WP columns and I use it in my [website](http://www.quantgreeks.com), it shifts my sidebar down. How to avoid this?

I would like my sidebar to remain at it original place.

Answer (score 0):

It looks it's not related to the plugin, try to remove that columns content and see what will happens. I just tried to remove it via firebug and sidebar is not aligned, so it looks to me that it's not related to the columns.

Comment: When I removed the comments content, it went back to normal. Tried before already.